# Python for android - import modules error

Tags: android, python, android-emulator

I am trying to import a python module in the "Python For Android" application in my emulator. I am able to push the zipped file and extract it but once the extraction is complete, I get the following error :-

```
Errorjava.io.
FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files/python/egg-info/hachoir-1.3.3.zip/files.txt(No such file or directory)
```

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: same thing here
and the same error is reported already here:
https://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/issues/detail?id=18

Comment: so How do I resolve this error ?? I ve been trying for months now !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it just by pressing the uninstall button within the python application. The first one. Mine didn't uninstall, instead out installed successfully the modules. Good luck!